# vbscript to disable/enable html input

Tags: html, vbscript, radio-button, hta

I have been working this one for a couple of days and I still haven't figured it out.  I have an HTML page that has two sets of inputs, each consisting of a radio button and some text.  I need:

- all of the text input to be disabled when the page loads
- radio button #1 to enable it's text input and disable the text inputs for radio button #2
- radio button #2 to enable it's text input and disable the text inputs for radio button #1

Here's some example code:

```
<html>

<script type="text/vbscript">
<!--<![CDATA[
function enable()
    if document.GetElementByID("radio1").checked then
        document.GetElementByID("radio2").checked = false
        document.GetElementByID("text1").disabled = false
        document.GetElementByID("text2").disabled = true
    elseif document.GetElementByID("radio2").checked then
        document.GetElementByID("radio1").checked = false
        document.GetElementByID("text1").disabled = true
        document.GetElementByID("text2").disabled = false
    else
        document.GetElementByID("text1").disabled = true
        document.GetElementByID("text2").disabled = true
    end if
end function
-->]]>
</script>

<body onload="enable()">
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio1" value="radio1" onclick="enable()">
                <label for="radio1" >
                    Radio 1
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" value="hi">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio2" value="radio2" onclick="enable()">
                <label for="radio2" >
                    Radio 2
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" value="bye">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

It looks like I can get it partially working, but not all the way.  Eventaully, this will end up in an HTA as a form.

---

EDIT:

Thanks to both @kingdomcreation and @Teemu, I now have this working solution for an arbitrary number of radio buttons:

```
<html>

    <script type="text/vbscript">
        <!--<![CDATA[
        function enable(num)
            document.getElementById("text" & num).disabled = false

            for i = 1 to 6
                if document.getElementById("radio" & i).checked = false Then
                    document.getElementById("text" & i).disabled = true
                end if
            next
        end function
        -->]]>
    </script>

    <body>
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="radio1" onClick="enable(1)">
                    <label for="radio1" >
                        Radio 1
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input disabled type="text" id="text1" name="text1" value="hi">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="radio2" onClick="enable(2)">
                    <label for="radio2" >
                        Radio 2
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input disabled type="text" id="text2" name="text2" value="there">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="radio3" onClick="enable(3)">
                    <label for="radio3" >
                        Radio 3
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input disabled type="text" id="text3" name="text3" value="how">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radio" value="radio4" onClick="enable(4)">
                    <label for="radio4" >
                        Radio 4
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input disabled type="text" id="text4" name="text4" value="are">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio5" name="radio" value="radio5" onClick="enable(5)">
                    <label for="radio5" >
                        Radio 5
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input disabled type="text" id="text5" name="text5" value="you">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio6" name="radio" value="radio6" onClick="enable(6)">
                    <label for="radio6" >
                        Radio 6
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input disabled type="text" id="text6" name="text6" value="bye">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working vbscript example i made to see what i could do to make it work in vbscript (on the client)

- Radio id can identify the one clicked on but to have the option of behaving like options (when one is clicked, the other becomes unchecked) the name attribute has to be the same.
- The vb code was placed under
- The function code was changed to vb syntax
- The document.GetElementByID was removed

I hope this clear up some things if you want to do client side vbscript... wich by the way is only supporter in IE appart for the ability to add extensions to other browsers.

```
<html>


<body onLoad="enable()">
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="radio1" onClick="enable()">
            <label for="radio1" >
                Radio 1
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1"  disabled value="hi">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio"  value="radio2" onClick="enable()">
            <label for="radio2" >
                Radio 2
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" disabled value="bye">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/vbscript">
<!--<![CDATA[
Function enable()
If radio1.checked = true Then
    radio2.checked = false
    text1.disabled = false
    text2.disabled = true
ElseIf radio2.checked = true Then
    radio1.checked = false
    text1.disabled = true
    text2.disabled = false
 Else
    text1.disabled = true
    text2.disabled = true
 End If
End Function
-->]]>
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This one has great promise. Thanks. I didn't realize the `name` attribute had to be the same for both buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can write disabled attribute on the input in the html so they are disabled by default (on load)

Comment: You're correct about the `disabled` attribute, but that's only part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have only two buttons, this does the trick. Notice the same `name` for both radio buttons. This way you can group radio buttons together, without a need to check/uncheck them separately. Also `onload()` becomes useless.

```
function enable(id)
    document.getElementById("text" & id).disabled = false
    document.getElementById("text" & id * -1).disabled = true
end function

<input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" value="radio1" onclick="enable(1)" />
<input id="text1" name="text1" type="text" value="hi" disabled />
                        :
<input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" value="radio2" onclick="enable(-1)" />
<input id="text-1" name="text2" type="text" value="bye" disabled />
```

Comment: I had forgotten this little trick.  It works well, but unfortunately there will be cases where there are more than two options.

Comment: I was actually able to use this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest something similar.

```
<html>

<script>
<!--<![CDATA[
function enable(){
    if( document.getElementById("radio1").checked){
        document.getElementById("radio2").checked = false
        document.getElementById("text1").disabled = false
        document.getElementById("text2").disabled = true
    }else if( document.getElementById("radio2").checked){
        document.getElementById("radio1").checked = false
        document.getElementById("text1").disabled = true
        document.getElementById("text2").disabled = false
    }else{
        document.getElementById("text1").disabled = true
        document.getElementById("text2").disabled = true
    }
}
-->]]>
</script>

<body onload="enable()">
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="radio1" onclick="enable()">
                <label for="radio1" >
                    Radio 1
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" value="hi">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="radio2" onclick="enable()">
                <label for="radio2" >
                    Radio 2
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" value="bye">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```